# Given that I have a field containing a username, how do I use that to populate another field with the corresponding user's Id?

Tags: custom-field, user

Given that I have a field containing a username, how do I use that to populate another field with the corresponding user's Id?

The field with the user name is filled from an outside program, the name of that user needs to be filled into the OwnerId of the task that is created based on the action they took in that outside program. OwnerId needs to be filled with an Id from the User which is why I want to know if it's possible to change the value in the text field into an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some difficulty understanding your question, but what I *think* you're asking is:
*Given that I have a field containing a username, how do I use that to populate another field with the corresponding user's Id?*

If that's accurate, then one answer to that is "by writing a SOQL query". E.g. `[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE FullName = 'your name here']`.

If you can't modify the code or automation that is creating this `Task`, then the place to perform this query is probably in a trigger on the `Task` SObject itself (because you could use the Task's `WhatId` to get back to your other object that has the Username, which could then be used for the query on `User`).

Comment: A flow _might_ also be able to achieve this, but it doesn't appear that there is a good way to build a map (username as the key, user id as the value) in a flow. As such, I don't think using a flow is a good fit for this scenario.